# Issues with Android WebView playing youtube video in default UnityPlayerActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview, unity-webgl

I want to load a WebView and play a video on youtube. What I did is added AndroidJavaProxy in unity and added a WebView using java code and when I clicked on the video it shows a black screen or a white screen sometimes.

But when I create a second activity from android and place the WebView loading code in that then playing the video works fine.

What I am speculating is UnityPlayerActivity is creating a UnityPlayer class and that is causing the issue. I have the demo projects for both the apps if anyone wants. Has someone faced something similar or has a solution for this ?
These two functions are present and second one works fine but video doesn't work in same activity though WebView loads fine in both the cases.

```
WebViewAndroid.Instance.AddWebViewInSameActivity("https://www.youtube.com");
WebViewAndroid.Instance.AddWebViewInNewActivity("https://www.youtube.com");
```

I have posted on Unity forums as well but no answer as of yet. Link : https://forum.unity.com/threads/issues-with-android-webview-playing-youtube-video-in-default-unityplayeractivity.1416288/#post-8899452

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this answer will met your requirements.
I used this code to play YouTube video inside my app...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(youtubeLink));
            intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This might be launching video in Youtube app in full screen but i dont want that.